# Capybara doesn't recognize dynamically added DOM elements?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, dom, integration-testing, capybara

I seem to be having trouble testing the slick javascript things I do with jQuery when using Capybara and Selenium.  The expected behavior is for a form to be dynamically generated when a user clicks on the link "add resource".  Capybara will be able to click the link, but fails to recognize the new form elements (i.e. "resource[name]").

Is there a way to reload the DOM for Capybara, or is there some element of this gem that I just haven't learned of yet?

Thanks in advance!

**==Edit==**

Currently trying my luck with selenium's:

```
wait_for_element
```

method.

**==Edit==**

I keep getting an "undefined method 'wait_for_element` for nill class" when attempting to do the following:

```
@selenium.wait_for_element
```

It appears that that specific method, or perhaps `wait_for` with a huge selector accessing the DOM element I expect is the correct course of action, but now trying to get the selenium session is starting to be a huge headache.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I use the Webdriver based driver for Capybara in RSpec, which I configure and use like this and it will definitely handle JS and doesn't need a reload of the dom.  The key is using a wait_until and a condition that will be true when your AJAX response has finished.

```
before(:each) do
  select_driver(example)  
  logout
  login('databanks') 
end

 def select_driver(example)
   if example.metadata[:js]
    Capybara.current_driver = :selenium
  else
    Capybara.use_default_driver
  end
end

it "should let me delete a scenario", :js=>true do
    select("Mysite Search", :from=>'scenario_id')  
    wait_until{ page.has_content?('mysite_searchterms')}    
    click_on "delete"     
    wait_until{ !page.has_content?('mysite_searchterms')}   
    visit '/databanks'
    page.should_not have_content('Mysite Search')
  end
```

I also figured out a hack to slow down webdriver last night, like this, if you want to watch things in slo-mo:

```
   #set a command delay
   require 'selenium-webdriver'

   module ::Selenium::WebDriver::Remote
     class Bridge
       def execute(*args)
         res = raw_execute(*args)['value']
         sleep 0.5
         res
       end
     end
   end
```

As someone else mentioned, if you are getting a timeout waiting for the element, you could look at upping this:

```
Capybara.default_wait_time = 10
```

Comment: thanks @ebeland. now after many months of using something similar in our tests at work, the `wait_until` method is without a doubt the correct way to go :)

Comment: `wait_until` has been removed from Capybara 2.0.0. [See this blog post](http://www.elabs.se/blog/53-why-wait_until-was-removed-from-capybara)

Answer (score 7):

From the Capybara docs:

> When working with asynchronous
>   JavaScript, you might come across
>   situations where you are attempting to
>   interact with an element which is not
>   yet present on the page. Capybara
>   automatically deals with this by
>   waiting for elements to appear on the
>   page.

You might have some luck increasing the wait time:

```
Capybara.default_wait_time = 10
```

If that doesn't help then I would encorage you to contact somebody from the project on GitHub, write to the mailing list or submit an issue report.

Comment: +1 here. Capybara uses this default wait time for method calls such as `has_selector?` `has_css?` and so on. So you can use these methods to wait for the element to appear, using something like: `has_css?("a#myinput", :visible => true)` which will wait until the element is on the screen before proceeding.

Comment: where should I put `Capybara.default_wait_time = 10`?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp in your `spec/rails_helper.rb` if you have one, otherwise your `spec/spec_helper.rb`.

Comment: What does Cucumber have to do with the directory of RSpec which is /spec?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp Nothing! This question is about using Capybara with RSpec, not about Cucumber.

Answer (score 0):

Even wait_until deleted from Capybara 2.0. Still that's useful and grab code from below:

```
 def wait_until(delay = 1)   
 seconds_waited = 0   
 while ! yield && seconds_waited < Capybara.default_wait_time     
    sleep delay     
    seconds_waited += 1   
  end   
  raise "Waited for #{Capybara.default_wait_time} seconds but condition did not become true" unless yield 
end
```