# Surefire rerun failing tests not working

Tags: java, maven, testing, maven-surefire-plugin, surefire

I want to rerun a test that I know will fail cause I am trying to test the Surefire parameter for re-running the failing tests. 
I tried running Maven with these two commands neither of them works as expected

```
-Dsurefire.rerunFailingTestsCount=2 -Dtest=TestThatFails test
```

and

```
-Dsurefire.rerunFailingTestsCount=2 -Dtest=TestThatFails surefire:test
```

Here is part of `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
    <artifactId>surefire-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.53.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
```

I was expecting that Surefire would restart the test after failure but Maven just throws this error, which I know how to solve but I want the test to be rerun.

```
Results :

Tests in error: 
  testA(selenium.services.TestThatWillFail): Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with(..)

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 55.060 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-11-24T12:58:02+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 18M/173M

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) on project eskn_selenium: There are test failures.
```

Comment: This is the correct way to use it. Chances are this was due to a buggy old surefire plugin, or more likely, junit/surefire incompatibility. From the docs: "This feature is supported for JUnit 4.x, and (since 3.0.0-M4) JUnit 5.x." (https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/rerun-failing-tests.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although that is missing from the documentation, the parameter [`rerunFailingTestsCount`](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#rerunFailingTestsCount) was introduced in version 2.18 of the Maven Surefire Plugin, as mentioned in [SUREFIRE-1087](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1087). Since you're using the default version of 2.12.4 (that comes from the Super POM), that option is not available.

Therefore, the fix is simply to update the Surefire version to a version that is at least 2.18; for example, the latest, which is currently 2.19.1:

```
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.19.1</version>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

Note that this parameter only works with JUnit 4+ (which is your case, since you have JUnit 4.12).

Comment: oooooh now I see ! 
I thought that adding it as dependency will do the work but it has to be added as plugin. I was about to ask if you did not notice that it is already defined in pom.xml haha.
Thank you!

Comment: Update for **JUnit 5**: Maven Surefire `3.0.0-M5` now lets you use `rerunFailingTestsCount` system property when executing tests. Make sure to pass the below property when running your `mvn clean` stage:

```-Dsurefire.rerunFailingTestsCount=3```

Comment: See the Feature Matrix for Surefire/Failsafe https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/featurematrix.html

Answer (score 16):

Just to add to Wim Rutgeerts's answer - `rerunFailingTestsCount` must be in the `configuration` section, not in `properties`, like this:

```
<configuration>
    <rerunFailingTestsCount>2</rerunFailingTestsCount>
</configuration>
```

In my case with `maven-surefire-plugin` 2.19.1 it worked this way. When it was in `properties` it did not work.

Answer (score 5):

Update for **JUnit 5**: Maven Surefire version `3.0.0-M4` or later now lets you use `rerunFailingTestsCount` system property when executing JUnit 5 tests.

Make sure to pass the below property when running your `mvn clean` stage:

```
-Dsurefire.rerunFailingTestsCount=3
```

Comment: You don't have to pass the property, you can also put it in `<configuration>` as documented in other answers.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using the command line property -Dsurefire.rerunFailingTestsCount=2, you can also define it in the pom in the properties section

```
 <properties>
    <surefire.rerunFailingTestsCount>2</surefire.rerunFailingTestsCount>
 </properties>
```