# rerunFailingTestsCount=N is not working for me

Tags: java, maven, selenium, maven-surefire-plugin, cucumber-junit

i am tryring to rerun the failed tests using maven surefire plugin using parameter "rerunFailingTestsCount=N"

i am not able to achieve retry with following POm and my runner class, tried with difference versions on maven Surefire from 2.19.1 onwards

any help around it is appreciated
***************my POM is as follow:***********************

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>OnlineTest</groupId>
    <artifactId>VehicleRegistrationTest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>${name}</name>
    <properties>
        <name>VehicleRegistration</name>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd-HHmm</maven.build.timestamp.format>
        <buildNumber>${maven.build.timestamp}</buildNumber>
        <reports.directory>${project.build.directory}/../reports/</reports.directory>
        <selenium.enabled>true</selenium.enabled>
        <test.parallel.count>2</test.parallel.count>
        <surefire.maven.plugin.version>2.20.1</surefire.maven.plugin.version>
        <cucumber.jvm.parallel.version>4.2.0</cucumber.jvm.parallel.version>
        <parallel.scheme>SCENARIO</parallel.scheme>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.mkolisnyk</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-runner</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-junit</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.mkolisnyk</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-report-generator</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.mkolisnyk</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-runner</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.mkolisnyk</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-runner</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.mkolisnyk</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-report-generator</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.mkolisnyk</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-runner</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.mkolisnyk</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-report-generator</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.mkolisnyk</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-report-generator</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>hindsighttesting.release</id>
            <name>Hindsight Software Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.hindsightsoftware.com/public-maven</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <forkCount>${test.parallel.count}</forkCount>
                    <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                    <workingDirectory>parallel-tests-fork-${surefire.forkNumber}</workingDirectory>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*testRunner.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <rerunFailingTestsCount>3</rerunFailingTestsCount>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.temyers</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${cucumber.jvm.parallel.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generateRunners</id>
                        <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generateRunners</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <glue>
                                <package>stepDefinition.Hooks</package>
                                <package>webDriver</package>
                                <package>stepDefinitions</package>
                            </glue>
                            <featuresDirectory>src/test/resources/featureFiles/</featuresDirectory>
                            <cucumberOutputDir>target/json-reports</cucumberOutputDir>
                            <format>json</format>
                            <parallelScheme>${parallel.scheme}</parallelScheme>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>report.donut</groupId>
                <artifactId>donut-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>execution</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirectory>${project.build.directory}/json-reports</sourceDirectory>
                            <outputDirectory>reports/testReports</outputDirectory>
                            <prefix>rcf-test-${maven.build.timestamp}</prefix>
                            <timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</timestamp>
                            <template>default</template>
                            <projectName>${project.name}</projectName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Werror</compilerArgument>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>




***************my testRunner class is as follow:*******************

    import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;


@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = {"featureFiles"},
        glue = {"stepDefinitions"},
        plugin ={"rerun:target/rerun.txt"}
)

public class testRunner { }
```

Comment: Which plugin you are using for execution. Surefire or failsafe?

Comment: How are you using that parameter in your mvn command

Comment: i use surefire to execute the failed test, command is : mvn clean verify -Dcucumber.tags=@test123 -Dfailsafe.rerunFailingTestsCount=3

Comment: also you can find my sample project for reference with the same configuration and same error at : https://github.com/tabu0024/VehicleRegistrationTest/tree/master

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Surefire rerun failing tests not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40785891/surefire-rerun-failing-tests-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue running cucumber tests using approximately the same versions, where scenarios were not getting retried.

Solution was to bump the fail-safe plugin version to **2.21.0** as well as bump the cucumber versions.

The hint is provided in the following page: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/rerun-failing-tests.html

> Since of 2.21.0 the provider surefire-junit47 can rerun scenarios
> created by cucumber-jvm 2.0.0 and higher.

So change the group `info.cukes` to `io.cucumber` and set version appropriately, e.g.:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
  <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

and the fail-safe plugin:

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.21.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>integration-tests</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>integration-test</goal>
          <goal>verify</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <systemProperties combine.children="append" />
          <rerunFailingTestsCount>2</rerunFailingTestsCount>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Note that the `rerunFailingTestsCount` parameter worked both in the configuration as shown here or as a property (e.g. `mvn clean verify -Dfailsafe.rerunFailingTestsCount=2`).