# Rerun falied test cases for cucumber jvm parallel

Tags: maven, selenium, cucumber

I have created test cases in cucumber with selenium. I am using parallel execution to run my test cases. Below is my pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.tests</groupId>
<artifactId>Sample-Cucumber</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<name>Sample Platform</name>
<description>Sample with Cucumber Implementation</description>
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <cucumber.version>1.2.3</cucumber.version>
    <extentreports.version>2.41.0</extentreports.version>
    <selenium.version>2.53.1</selenium.version>
    <cucumber.jvm.parallel.version>2.1.0</cucumber.jvm.parallel.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.temyers</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.jvm.parallel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sitture</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-extentreport</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.directory.studio</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.commons.codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>win</id>
        <activation>
            <os>
                <family>windows</family>
            </os>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <webdriver.chrome.path>${basedir}${file.separator}resources${file.separator}chromedriver.exe</webdriver.chrome.path>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>linux</id>
        <activation>
            <os>
                <family>!windows</family>
            </os>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <webdriver.chrome.path>resources${file.separator}chromedriver</webdriver.chrome.path>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.temyers</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.jvm.parallel.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generateRunners</id>
                    <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generateRunners</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <glue>com.cucumber.stepdefinitions</glue>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-test-sources/cucumber</outputDirectory>
                        <featuresDirectory>src/test/resources/features/</featuresDirectory>
                        <cucumberOutputDir>target/cucumber-parallel</cucumberOutputDir>
                        <format>json,html,rerun</format>
                        <strict>true</strict>
                        <monochrome>true</monochrome>
                        <useTestNG>false</useTestNG>
                        <namingPattern>Parallel{c}IT</namingPattern>
                        <namingScheme>simple</namingScheme>
                        <parallelScheme>SCENARIO</parallelScheme>
                        <tags>"~@ignore"</tags>
                        <filterFeaturesByTags>true</filterFeaturesByTags>
                        <useJUnitReRun>true</useJUnitReRun>
                        <retryCount>1</retryCount>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19</version>
            <configuration>
                <additionalClasspathElements>
                    <additionalClasspathElement>resources</additionalClasspathElement>
                </additionalClasspathElements>
                <!-- Increase Fork Count to increase parallel execution count.
                Currently it is set to 5 which means 5 runners will run in parallel-->
                <forkCount>2</forkCount>
                <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/Parallel*IT.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>perform</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <pomFileName>${basedir}${file.separator}pom.xml</pomFileName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I have created a jenkin job to trigger the build. I use *mvn clean install* OR *mvn clean verify* to trigger the tests. Since I am running the tests in parallel, there are separate reports/rerun files created for each parallel run.
The reports are consolidated by plugin however my failed test cases are not executed.

I referred the post here: https://github.com/sugatmankar/cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin-rerun-example and included rerun tag in pom.xml

Also, I referred the post here: [Rerunning failed cucumber tests using cucumber-jvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21334207/rerunning-failed-cucumber-tests-using-cucumber-jvm) but I would avoid using a custom listener for failed cases.

I am not sure if I am doing something wrong in the pom.xml file or should I be running the test cases differently

The build tag in the xml file invokes the test. However, I am not sure why the following piece is not being triggered

```
<useJUnitReRun>true</useJUnitReRun>
                    <retryCount>1</retryCount>
```

I am trying to understand why this is not being called and if there is a working sample which I could refer

Comment: Not sure why the question was downvoted. Could someone please mention the reason for downvote?

Comment: So it runs fine outside jenkins? (I haven't downvoted, just asking out of curiosity)

Comment: No. Even when I am running it through command prompt or terminal, it would not initiate the retry logic

Comment: I think you enclose too much information, could you please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).