# How to retry a failed cucumber test twice?

Tags: java, testing, gradle, cucumber, automated-tests

I'm using jenkins, gradle, cucumber and java to run end-to-end tests.

I want to retry every failing test twice.

How can I configure any of the frameworks above to do so?

Comment: In general failing test indicates that something is wrong. Taking it into consideration, why You want these failing tests to be repeated?

Comment: A test that fails sometimes when things aren't "broken" isn't a useful test. Instead of running it multiple times hoping for a pass, spend your time trying to get the test to be less brittle.

Comment: sometimes my environment fails for a second and a retry will help. I usually use webdriver.wait But i'll love to know how to retry anyway

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to rerun the failed scenarios using Cucumber?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719898/how-to-rerun-the-failed-scenarios-using-cucumber)