# How to define re-run task in cucumber using gradle?

Tags: java, jenkins, cmd, automation, gradle

I have seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719898/how-to-rerun-the-failed-scenarios-using-cucumber) on how to re-run failed tasks in cucumber.

I'm using jenkins IC and gradle as build tool.

How would you create a re-run task?

1. Using gradle task?
   What syntax is used in my `build.gradle` today? Shell script?

   `run {
       args += ['-f', 'html:build/reports/cucumber/', '-f',   'json:build/reports/cucumber/report.json', '--glue', 'com.waze.testing.cucumber', 'src/main/resources/features', '--tags', '~@ignore']
   }`
2. Writing python scrip? The problem is I don't remember python.
3. Using any jenkins cucumber plugin?
   (I have this plug in, but didn't see any helpful step)

Comment: I guess You can use gradle task of type `Exec`. You can find docs here: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html

Comment: what is the syntax in build.gradle called? what kind of script is it?

Comment: Is saw this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24895370/how-can-i-run-new-gradle-task. The way of usage `Exec` task is good.

Comment: I don't know cucumber, but you might find some inspiration in the script I posted in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48815890/how-to-re-run-only-failed-junit-test-classes-using-gradle