# How can I run new gradle task?

Tags: bash, shell, intellij-idea, automation, gradle

I have created a new gradle task in build.gradle:

```
task callCL(type: Exec) {
   println "hello"
   commandLine './rerun.sh'
}
```

Which suppose to run rerun.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

cucumber -f rerun --out rerun.txt

file="rerun.txt"
if [ -f "$file" ] then
    cucumber @rerun.txt
    rm $file
fi
```

I'm using IntelliJ as an IDE. How can I run this task?

I have tried to run in the zshell console and got this error:

> > gradle callCL
> >     zsh: command not found: gradle

But in the IDE I use gradle all the time so it must be installed.

How can I fix this? And is my writing ok?

Comment: Does your IDE know where is GRADLE_HOME and what GRADLE_OPTS are set as? Is PATH variable has <GRADLE_HOME>/bin folder in it? Try to run it from command prompt first. If you use Cygwin, you can also try "which gradle" to find out if it resolves to a valid file with path OR see Windows Environment variables for the above ENV variables.

Comment: You can also use gradle wrapper.

Comment: can you please add an answer showing how you would use the wrapper to run the script?

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**: 
1. Make sure GRADLE_HOME, GRADLE_OPTS are set. 
2. Make sure $PATH has GRADLE_HOME/bin in it.
3. *which gradle* should return you a valid output. 
4. then, see below
, if this works on command prompt, then your IDE setting just need to know where's is GRADLE_HOME aka its installed / executable (either gradle or gradle.bat)

*NOTE:* I have used my own dummy rerun.sh file, you can you use build.gradle (as shown below).

**$ cat rerun.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Im re-running a command echo
echo something
echo ...
echo
```

**$ cat build.gradle**

```
task callCL(type: Exec) {
        println "-----"
        println "hello"
        println "-----"
        executable "bash"
        args "-c", "bash ./rerun.sh"

        //The following will do as well as magic number in bash is already set to #!/bin/bash
        //args "-c", "./rerun.sh"
}
```

**$ /cygdrive/c/gradle-2.0/bin/gradle callCL**

```
-----
hello
-----
:callCL
Im re-running a command echo
something
...

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 2.006 secs
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like problem with gradle not being found on path (in your shell).

You may use [GVM](http://gvmtool.net/) to easily install gradle so that its available on your `PATH`.