# cucumber jvm FAILED FAILURE: Build failed with an exception

Tags: java, shell, gradle, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I try to run this gradle task (via gradlew)

which uses cucmber jvm

```
task callCL (type: Exec) {
    commandLine './build/distributions/WebLargeTests/bin/WebLargeTests  -f html:build/reports/cucumber/ -f json:build/reports/cucumber/report.json --glue com.mayApp.testing.cucumber src/main/resources/features --tags ~@ignore -f rerun'
}
```

and get this error

```
:callCL FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':callCL'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command './build/distributions/WebLargeTests/bin/WebLargeTests  -f html:build/reports/cucumber/ -f json:build/reports/cucumber/report.json --glue com.myApp.testing.cucumber src/main/resources/features --tags ~@ignore -f rerun''

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.448 secs
error=2, No such file or directory
3:48:00 PM: External task execution finished 'callCL'.
```

when I run the same line from the same path in cmd:

```
/build/distributions/WebLargeTests/bin/WebLargeTests  -f html:build/reports/cucumber/ -f json:build/reports/cucumber/report.json --glue com.myApp.testing.cucumber src/main/resources/features --tags ~@ignore -f rerun
Starting ChromeDriver (v2.9.248307) on port 12095
Starting ChromeDriver (v2.9.248307) on port 34150
Starting ChromeDriver (v2.9.248307) on port 29495
Starting ChromeDriver (v2.9.248307) on port 8792
Starting ChromeDriver (v2.9.248307) on port 23779
Starting ChromeDriver (v2.9.248307) on port 3553
```

**update1:**

this cmd works in a shell console:

./build/distributions/WebLargeTests/bin/WebLargeTests  -f html:build/reports/cucumber/ -f json:build/reports/cucumber/report.json --glue com.waze.testing.cucumber src/main/resources/features --tags @only -f rerun

but not in the build.gradle

```
task callCL (type: Exec) {
    commandLine 'bash', './build/distributions/WebLargeTests/bin/WebLargeTests', '-f',
            'html:build/reports/cucumber/', '-f', 'json:build/reports/cucumber/report.json', '--glue',
            'com.waze.testing.cucumber', 'src/main/resources/features', '--tags', '@ignore', '-f', 'rerun'

    //store the output instead of printing to the console:
    standardOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream()

    //extension method stopTomcat.output() can be used to obtain the output:
    ext.output = {
        return standardOutput.toString()
    }
}
```

btw

I want the cmd to be:

./build/distributions/WebLargeTests/bin/WebLargeTests  -f html:build/reports/cucumber/ -f json:build/reports/cucumber/report.json --glue com.waze.testing.cucumber src/main/resources/features --tags @only -f rerun --out rerun.txt

but not in the build.gradle

```
task callCL (type: Exec) {
    commandLine 'bash', './build/distributions/WebLargeTests/bin/WebLargeTests', '-f',
            'html:build/reports/cucumber/', '-f', 'json:build/reports/cucumber/report.json', '--glue',
            'com.waze.testing.cucumber', 'src/main/resources/features', '--tags', '@ignore', '-f', 'rerun', '--out', 'rerun.txt'

    //store the output instead of printing to the console:
    standardOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream()

    //extension method stopTomcat.output() can be used to obtain the output:
    ext.output = {
        return standardOutput.toString()
    }
}
```

but this doesn't work (shell concole nore build.gradle)

Comment: You've `commandLine` wrong defined for sure. Should be e.g.: `commandLine 'bash','script.sh'`

Comment: added `commandLine 'bash','` and got:  Process 'command 'bash'' finished with non-zero exit value 127

Comment: This is not a problem of `bash` in the beginning of command, but all command args should be esacped with `'` separately.

Comment: so I ran:
`    task callCL (type: Exec) {
        commandLine 'bash', './build/distributions/WebLargeTests/bin/WebLargeTests', '-f',
        'html:build/reports/cucumber/', '-f', 'json:build/reports/cucumber/report.json', '--glue',
        'com.waze.testing.cucumber', 'src/main/resources/features', '--tags', '@ignore', '--out', 'rerun.txt'
    }` and got: `:callCL FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':callCL'.
> Process 'command 'bash'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: Add output handling to see errors: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html

Comment: tried, but saw no additional info:* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':callCL'.
> Process 'command 'bash'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.344 secs
Process 'command 'bash'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
5:03:23 PM: External task execution finished 'callCL'.

Comment: Is this command working when run just from command line?

Comment: yes. That's why i'm lost

Comment: Ok. Paste here the full argument You pass to `commandLine` in exec task.

Comment: Still not sure if `bash` is needed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24895370/how-can-i-run-new-gradle-task -- you mean this won't help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works!

Note: I'm using /build/... path instead of using a dot first then slash: ./build/...

```
task callCL(type: Exec) {

        executable "bash"
        args "-c", "bash /build/distributions/WebLargeTests/bin/WebLargeTests -f html:build/reports/cucumber/ -f json:build/reports/cucumber/report.json --glue com.waze.testing.cucumber src/main/resources/features --tags @only -f rerun"


        // If you want the store the output to a file, you can also try the following
        //args "-c", "bash /build/distributions/WebLargeTests/bin/WebLargeTests -f html:build/reports/cucumber/ -f json:build/reports/cucumber/report.json --glue com.waze.testing.cucumber src/main/resources/features --tags @only -f rerun 1>/some/path/somefile.log 2>&1"

        //store the output instead of printing to the console:
        standardOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream()

        //extension method stopTomcat.output() can be used to obtain the output:
        ext.output = {
           return standardOutput.toString()
        }
}
```