# Output only failed scenarios to a file in cucumber

Tags: cucumber

I know how to output the entire cucumber output using `cucumber --out #file_name` but I just want to output the failed scenarios to a file and not output the passed scenarios. How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Check out this SO answer:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719898/how-to-rerun-the-failed-scenarios-using-cucumber

Comment: It prints out just the line numbers of the failed scenarios but I want to be able to print the error messages too @orde

Answer (score 0):

I made formatter for this (ruby only!): 
https://gist.github.com/foton/d317e1b3371021fee964 .
Just put this file to `features/support` and run cucumber with `-f` option.
There are 4 different formatters. Difference is how the stacktrace and message is ordered/formatted.

```
cucumber -f Cucumber::Formatter::Failures features/some.feature 
cucumber -f Cucumber::Formatter::Failures::OneLine features/some.feature 
cucumber -f Cucumber::Formatter::Failures::TwoLines features/some.feature 
cucumber -f Cucumber::Formatter::Failures::StacktraceFirst features/some.feature
```