# Integrating Junit with Ruby-Cucumber-Watir?

Tags: ruby, junit, cucumber

Is it possible to integrate Junit with Ruby-Cucumber framework? If so, is there any documentation available for this?

Comment: In ruby, a testing suite like `minitest` or `rspec` would typically be used in conjunction with cucumber.  Is there reason you don't want to use one of those?  You'll find lots of examples and documentation on SO and the interweb...

Comment: Right now i am using rspec. But i have a scenario like re-run failed tests and update the status etc. i didnt get much help on that. In fact it is not very easy in rspec. So thought, if there is a test framework available with these features, i can use that. I have used testNG and there is a way in testNG to re-run the failed tests. Just wanted to check the other framework and understand which is very good for our project.

Comment: Try running the failed tests via cucumber?  Check out this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719898/how-to-rerun-the-failed-scenarios-using-cucumber