# Protractor/cucumberjs rerunning failed tests/cucumber features/specs

Tags: protractor, ui-automation, e2e-testing, cucumberjs, webdriverjs

Given that automated UI tests sometimes fail due to flakiness, an ability to rerun only the failed tests becomes incredibly useful in a framework like protractor. 
Unfortunately, as of 09/13/2016, there's no way to rerun failed tests with protractor.

***How do you guys rerun your failed tests? Ideally, I'd like suggestions/ideas from people using the javascript implementation of cucumber, cucumberJs.***

There's [protractor-flake](https://github.com/NickTomlin/protractor-flake) that was developped by [Nick Tomlin](https://github.com/NickTomlin) to address this problem but that module doesn't always work when dealing with multicapabilities where you're trying to run your tests in parallel.

***A. How do you guys rerun your failed tests? Ideally, I'd like suggestions/ideas from people using the javascript implementation of cucumber, cucumberJs.***

There's protractor-flake that was developped by Nick Tomlin to address this problem but that module doesn't always work when dealing with multicapabilities where you're trying to run your tests in parallel.
There's protractor-flake that was developped by Nick Tomlin to address this problem but that module doesn't always work when dealing with multicapabilities where you're trying to run your tests in parallel.

This question: [How to rerun the failed scenarios using Cucumber?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719898/how-to-rerun-the-failed-scenarios-using-cucumber) almost answered the question; problem is: how do I use that command (***cucumber -f rerun --out rerun.txt***) to rerun my tests AND run protractor in parallel? That command might only work when you're not parallelizing your protractor tests;

***B. How would you use that cucumber command to run your tests in parallel?***

Please answer question A and B above, thanks again!

Comment: See my answer over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58096754/how-to-rerun-the-failed-cucumber-scenarios-in-protractor/58964441#58964441), it is now pretty simple to do this.

Answer (score 0):

So far I have found the following tool, protractor-flake, that will rerun failed protractor tests:

```
***Github***: https://github.com/NickTomlin/protractor-flake
***NPM***: https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-flake
```