# How to rerun the failed cucumber scenarios in protractor?

Tags: typescript, protractor, automated-tests, cucumberjs

As a part of testing, i was using typescript language to develop the code which will be compatible for protractor, i was using BDD framework in which i had defined some cucumber options in my config.ts as following:

```
capabilities: {

    specs: "../example.feature"
}

cucumberOpts: {

    compiler: "ts:ts-node/register",
    format: "rerun:./reports/rerun.txt",
    require: "../../stepdefinations/*.ts",
    strict: true
}

onComplete: () =>{

    Reporter.createHTMLReport();
}
```

As mentioned in format, i was able to get the failed scenario line numbers in the rerun.txt which contains as following:
example.feature:145:439

How to run this file before completing the test suite, how to rerun the failed scenarios for 3 times

Comment: "failed cucumber scenarios in protractor" sounds like a disappointing geometry salad.

Answer (score 4):

As of November 2019, you can simply add `retry: 3` (or however many retries you want to allow) to your `cucumberOpts`.

There is one issue with this regarding the process still returning an exit code of 1 after retried failures succeed, I have opened issues with Protractor and `protractor-cucumber-framework` trying to address this.

Comment: What's the Cucumber.js version this feature is supported? Never heard this before.

Comment: I tried t use it. I don't think its retrying a failed test scenario in my Protractor-Cucumber.js framework. Do you have a working sample?

Comment: Believe this is all in Cucumber 6. Upgrade to the latest Cucumber and Protractor.

Comment: I updated to latest 6.0.5 version [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cucumber) but didn't see retry feature working. I don't know if I'm missing something.

Comment: I finally got it working after I completely removed node_modules and did **npm install**. Many thanks to you.

Comment: @HarishaKP glad to hear!

Answer (score 1):

You can not currently rerun the failed tests in the same suite as your initial run. What it sounds like you want is retry functionality which there are actually pull requests up for

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/pull/1229
https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/pull/1205/commits

What you need to do right now is rerun cucumber again against that txt file, to learn how to do that, check out https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/cli.md#formats