# Rerun multiple failed cucumber feature

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I'am using Ruby, Cucumber and Watir for UI automation and pretty much new to it.I'm trying to rerun failed tests using cucumber.

I'm creating `rerun.txt` with rerun formatter, which contains multiple failed feature files path. Eg. below is rerun.txt content on failure :

```
features/test_suites/Test1.feature:12
features/test_suites/homepage/Test2.feature:9:30
```

When I execute `cucumber @rerun.txt`, it executes only the first feature file with failed scenarios and does not execute other feature files mentioned in `rerun.txt`.

Can any one please help me rerunning all failed feature files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rerun the failed scenarios using Cucumber?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719898/how-to-rerun-the-failed-scenarios-using-cucumber)

Comment: @Marit I think it is a different question - "Why my rerun.txt runs only first scenario"

Answer (score 1):

After analysis , I found that the rerun content was not getting generated as expected for cucumber.
Each path for failed scenario of different feature file should be separated by single space.

Issue resolved. Cheers!!