# Cucumber how to re-run fail scenarios with RubyMine IDE

Tags: automation, rubygems, automated-tests, cucumber, watir

[![Try to run from ruby mine]I was not able to rerun failed automated test scenarios by using yml file example  default: --no-source --color cucumber -f rerun --out rerun.txt

[image: Try to run from RubyMine ide]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rerun the failed scenarios using Cucumber?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719898/how-to-rerun-the-failed-scenarios-using-cucumber)

Comment: When i run all scenarios as batch, some time one scenarios fail , if i rerun that scenarios, it pass. I am trying to rerun automatically only failed scenarios and it will make test results all pass.                                            " cucumber -f rerun --out rerun.txt  "    it will not work automatically. Also how it will work in jenkins ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the Runner Options. **Steps**: Open Feature file > Run menu > Edit Configuration > Cucumber > Add/Edit existing > Update Runner Options.

[image: Edit Runner Options Image]

Comment: Thanks, Dijkgraaf! Don't have enough reputation to add inline images :)