# Cucumber Maven rerun, run's all scenarios instead of the failed ones

Tags: java, maven, cucumber

I have the following runner class:

```
@CucumberOptions(
   features = {"src/test/java/resources/features/"},
   glue = {"stepDefinition"},
   monochrome = true,
   tags = "@Test",
   plugin = {"pretty", "junit:target/cucumber-junitReports/Cucumber.xml", "html:target/cucumber-htmlReports" + ".html", "json:target/cucumber-report/cucumber.json","json:target/cucumber-jsonReports/report.json","rerun:target/rerun.txt"})
```

I then run the test using `mvn test -Dcucumber.filter.tags=@Test`. If tests fail they are written to the rerun.txt file.

I then run `mvn clean test -Dcucumber.options="@rerun.txt" -Dcucumber.filter.tags=@$Test`
but I noticed it runs' all the tests with the `@Test` tag and not the ones failing in the rerun.txt file.
My rerun.txt file looks like this `file:src/test/java/resources/features/project/game/gamepage.feature:15`

Don't know if it is necessary but I will include my POM file.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Automation</groupId>
    <artifactId>Project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Game Automation</name>
    <description>GameAutomation Project</description>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                        <fork>true</fork>
                        <!--<executable>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\javac.exe</executable> -->
                        <executable>${env.JAVA_HOME}\bin\javac.exe</executable>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*Rerun.java</include>
                        </includes>
                        <rerunFailingTestsCount>2</rerunFailingTestsCount>
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                        <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.trivago.rta</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cluecumber-report-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>report</id>
                            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>reporting</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <customPageTitle>Automated Test Results</customPageTitle>
                        <customParameters>
                            <Custom_Parameter>Automated Test Results</Custom_Parameter>
                            <_Text>Results ForAutomated Test Results</_Text>
                        </customParameters>
                        <expandBeforeAfterHooks>true</expandBeforeAfterHooks>
                        <sourceJsonReportDirectory>${project.build.directory}/cucumber-report</sourceJsonReportDirectory>
                        <generatedHtmlReportDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-report</generatedHtmlReportDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0-beta-3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-html -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-html</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-jvm-deps -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.6</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/gherkin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
            <version>16.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-picocontainer -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.aventstack/extentreports -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber4-adapter</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.freemarker/freemarker -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.30</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.masterthought/cucumber-reporting -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java8 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.trivago.rta</groupId>
            <artifactId>cluecumber-report-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.ashot</groupId>
            <artifactId>ashot</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>7.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20210307</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0-beta-3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0-beta-3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-chrome-driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0-beta-3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-json</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0-beta-3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I've tried the following [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49132447/rerunning-the-failed-scenario-using-maven-cucumber-serenity) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21334207/rerunning-failed-cucumber-tests-using-cucumber-jvm/55032527#55032527) but it runs all test.
Is there something I am missing, or a better way of doing a rerun.?