# How to Rerun a Particular Cucumber Scenario when it Fails with Cucumber

Tags: java, maven, cucumber

I know how to use two runner classes to rerun failed scenarios, but I want this feature only for one test.

Let's say that I have 100 scenarios and I only want to rerun scenario 40 when it fails, but if any other scenaria fails, I don't want it to rerun. Is there a way to implement this for one test in particular?

To see how to rerun all failed scenarios, check out this question:
[How to rerun the failed scenarios using Cucumber?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719898/how-to-rerun-the-failed-scenarios-using-cucumber)

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to write custom code for this. Fortunately this is relatively easy with the JUnit Platform API (JUnit 5).

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-junit-platform-engine#rerunning-failed-scenarios

```
package com.example;

import org.junit.platform.engine.discovery.DiscoverySelectors;
import org.junit.platform.engine.discovery.UniqueIdSelector;
import org.junit.platform.launcher.Launcher;
import org.junit.platform.launcher.LauncherDiscoveryRequest;
import org.junit.platform.launcher.TestIdentifier;
import org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherFactory;
import org.junit.platform.launcher.listeners.SummaryGeneratingListener;
import org.junit.platform.launcher.listeners.TestExecutionSummary.Failure;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import static org.junit.platform.engine.discovery.DiscoverySelectors.selectDirectory;
import static org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.request;

public class RunCucumber {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      LauncherDiscoveryRequest request = request()
              .selectors(
                      selectDirectory("path/to/features")
              )
              .build();

      Launcher launcher = LauncherFactory.create();
      SummaryGeneratingListener listener = new SummaryGeneratingListener();
      launcher.registerTestExecutionListeners(listener);
      launcher.execute(request);

      TestExecutionSummary summary = listener.getSummary();
      // Do something with summary

      List<UniqueIdSelector> failures = summary.getFailures().stream()
              .map(Failure::getTestIdentifier)
              .filter(TestIdentifier::isTest)
              // Filter more to select scenarios to rerun
              .map(TestIdentifier::getUniqueId)
              .map(DiscoverySelectors::selectUniqueId)
              .collect(Collectors.toList());

      LauncherDiscoveryRequest rerunRequest = request()
              .selectors(failures)
              .build();

      launcher.execute(rerunRequest);

      TestExecutionSummary rerunSummary = listener.getSummary();
      // Do something with rerunSummary

   }

}
```