# Cucumber for Java - Immediately rerunning a Gherkin feature file after it fails

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit, cucumber, cucumber-java

I have a Java project that uses Cucumber 7, Maven surefire, and JUnit 4. It is a project requirement to be able to rerun a failed feature file immediately after it fails (not rerun after the entire test run as done normally). So the flow would be something like:

1. Run BeforeAll()
2. Run Before()
3. Run test
4. If test fails, rerun until MAX_RETRY(2) is reached
5. Run After()
6. Do Steps 2-5 until all tests are run
7. Run AfterAll()

I've seen people using Cucumber listeners for similar-ish problems but that is not an option for me as I'm on 7.3.3 and the EventListener is deprecated (AFAIK). Also read something about an [extended Cucumber runner](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/deconstruction-cucumber-junit-runner-behaviour-sumon-dey) but is outdated. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73394344/how-to-rerun-a-particular-cucumber-scenario-when-it-fails-with-cucumber) is the closest response I found but uses Junit5. I've tried using the `rerunFailingTestsCount` parameter through Maven Surefire but that reruns the features after the entire test suite is run. If you have any other suggestions, I would be very grateful. Thanks!

This is my current Cucumber Runner (without rerun implemented). I run the main() to execute my tests.

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        tags="@xxx",
        plugin = {"pretty"},
        features = {"classpath:features"},
        glue = {"StepDefinitions"}
)

public class Runner {
    private static String[] options = {
            "classpath:Features",
            "--glue", "StepDefinitions",
            "--tags", "@xxx",
            "--plugin", "pretty",
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Stream<String> cucumberOptions = Stream.concat(Stream.of(defaultOptions), Stream.of(args));
            ClassLoader contextClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
            byte exitstatus = Main.run(cucumberOptions.toArray(String[]::new), contextClassLoader);

            // other stuff done for custom pdf reports
    }

}
```

Comment: It is not possible. Cucumber-JVM doesn't support retrying.

Comment: Sad. What about the solution that uses Junit5? Would it be possible to do it that way if I upgraded Junit?

Comment: Nope. That solution also executes cucumber twice. Generally speaking, I suspect nobody contributed this feature because it's pretty complicated. Detecting and retrying failed operations in the step however is pretty easy. Though personally I prefer to make the system under test stable so retrying isn't needed or make the tests wait for the appropriate condition if the action under test is asynchronous.